# JSON file - how to delete entire node that contains a string

Tags: json, powershell

I have a `JSON` file:

```
{ 
   "JSONS" : [ 
      { 
         "id" : "ToRemove", 
         "First" : [ 
            { 
               "id" : "geo", 
               "Name" : "Person1", 
               "model" : [ 
               ], 
               "adjustments" : [ 
                  { 
                     "uid" : "3", 
                     "name" : "4s", 
                     "value" : "1"
                  }, 
                  { 
                     "uid" : "5", 
                     "name" : "3s", 
                     "value" : "6"
                  }
               ]
            }, 
            { 
               "id" : "Meters", 
               "Dictionary" : "4.2"
            }, 
            { 
               "id" : "Moon", 
               "Filter" : "0.5", 
               "Saturn" : { 
                  "s" : "0", 
                  "v" : "1"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to delete entire node, if the `"id"`, in this example, contains `"ToRemove"` string. Everyting between `{` and `},` including those lines also, to make the final `JSON` consistent.

[This is a screenshot what I want to get rid of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w23Br.png).

I only found how to delete properties, but not entire nodes. I've tried to appli something like this:

```
$ToRemove = Get-Content $SourceFile  | ConvertFrom-Json
$ToRemove.PSObject.Object.Remove('id:','ToRemove')
$ToRemove | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File $DestFile
```

but of course it didn't work.
How to delete the entire node? I would love to use an array to put all strings I would like to delete.

Comment: Have you tried using [JQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)?

Comment: Using JQ: `jq 'del(.[] | select(.id == "ToRemove"))' $SourceFile`

Comment: JQ snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/MWE-Kp1UO1V

Comment: @CarloCorradini Snippet works OK, but after installing jq, it gives me an error:
`jq: error: ToRemove/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
del(.[] | select(.id == ToRemove))
jq: 1 compile error`

Comment: How do you invoke jq? Paste the command

Comment: @CarloCorradini The entire script looks like this: `$SourceFile = 'k:\TESTFile.json'
jq 'del(.[] | select(.id == "ToRemove"))' $SourceFile
` I've never used JQ before so I have no idea how to use it correctly within the PS script

Comment: It works, you must separate the commands:

Comment: $sourceFile = './test.json'

Comment: Without seeing a real Json is hard to help

Comment: jq 'del(.[] | select(.id == "ToRemove"))' $sourceFile

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon ahah true, I supposed it's an array of objects

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us valid json we can work with

Comment: @CarloCorradini Apologies, I've edited the original JSON file. May be it is not a standard file, that's why it is not working with JQ?

Comment: Here you go: `jq 'del(.JSONS[] | select(.id == "ToRemove"))' $SourceFile`

Comment: If you remove the entire object `{` `}` in your Json in this example you would end up with a `JSONS` property and an empty array. Is that right? Or what exactly you want to remove from it

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I want to get rid of this: `https://i.imgur.com/kF5LM1C.png`

Comment: Yup, my assumption is right then you would end up with an empty array

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Thank you, I will try to make it to work (it still gives me that error, but I am sure I am doing something wrong and I can figure it out. The original JSON file is 1GB long and it has multiple nodes. I wanted just to remove some of them (based on a string) and leave others intact. I will also get more familiar with JQ, it seems like a good tool, and I am about to deal with more JSON files, that are also new to me, so yeah, going to get familiar with that tool.

Comment: @CarloCorradini if jq is run from powershell you have to backslash the doublequotes

Comment: @js2010 nope, I've tried in my PowerShell and it works. Note that I've used ' and not "

Comment: @CarloCorradini Not for me in Windows 10.  `jq 'del(.JSONS[] | select(.id == \"ToRemove\"))' file.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can remove that object having the property `id = ToRemove` by filtering *where `id` is not equal to `ToRemove`* and assigning that result to the `.JSONS` property:

```bash
$json = Get-Content path\to\json.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.JSONS = @($json.JSONS.Where{ $_.id -ne 'ToRemove' })
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

The end result in this case would be an empty array for the `.JSONS` property:

```json
{
  "JSONS": []
}
```

[`.PSObject.Properties.Remove(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfocollection-1.remove?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-psmemberinfocollection-1-remove(system-string)) wouldn't be useful in this case because what it does is remove properties from one object but what you want to do is filter out an entire object based on a condition.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with this solution. I will test it on other files, but I am sure it will work.

Comment: The script works well (slow but it's fine - files are from 50 to 500MB) on various files I've tested it with. Now I have another problem. I've defined an array, `$2Del` and I want the script to remove more nodes at a time. If I replace `'2Remove'` with `$2Del`, I do not get an error, but no entry from the array is deleted from the file. Could you tell me how to utilise an array in this script? It seems that an array does not work with `-ne`, but works with `-eq` (but that's not what I want - it removes every other nodes except those in the array) :)

Comment: @KolesGit you're likely looking for `.Where{ $_.id -notin $arrayOfIds })` if that's not the case please ask a new question with the details

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use just plain PowerShell, like this:

```json
{
   "JSONS" : [ 
      { 
         "id" : "ToRemove", 
         "First" : [ 
            { 
               "id" : "geo", 
               "Name" : "Person1", 
               "model" : [ 
               ]
            }, 
            { 
               "id" : "Meters", 
               "Dictionary" : "4.2"
            }
         ]
      },
      { 
         "id" : "DontRemove", 
         "First" : []
      }
   ]
}
```

```
$json = Get-Content -Path $SourceFile  | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.JSONS = $json.JSONS | Where-Object { $_.Id -ne "ToRemove" }
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File -Path $DestFile
```